# ASP.Net Core UseExceptionHandler not handling all exceptions?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.Net Core 2 web api project.
I have added the following to the `Configure` method in my Startup.cs file
`app.UseExceptionHandler();`

I noticed in my Postman tests that I was getting an "Unable to get response" result.
Server-side logging shows that the error has to do with Tables being missing from my Database.  Which is fine, I can resolve that.  But my question is why would the server not be returning a 500 Internal Server Error?  Why is it dying, and returning no response at all to Postman?

So, in my Controller, I purposely throw an Exception to test the handler, and call the URL from Postman, and indeed, I get back a 500 Internal server error response, as expected.

Why are the "deeper down" errors being thrown from EFCore not being handled by the ExceptionHandler middleware, and crashing my app?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Depends on where the exception is thrown from. Did you try debugging to see if it happens on the request path?

Answer (score 5):

In your startup.cs, move the `UseMvc()` tag to the bottom of the pipeline i.e.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  ...
  app.UseExceptionHandler();
  app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute(); 
}
```

In my case, the request pipeline faulted on startup when the route launched by the browser did not exist. In that scenario, my app.UseExceptionHandler() before the app.UseMvc() was not executed.